# bootstrap blocking jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i need to use slideDown function from jQuery, which requires the content to be animated to be put under class " .hide ",

for .hide I had this in my custom css :

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

which conflicted with Bootstrap css as it contains :

```
.hide {
    display: none !important;
}
```

thus when i linked both these stylesheets, slideDown was'nt working, then i tried diffrent variations of .hide in both files, finally removing  .hide from my custom css file completely worked,

so my ques is why does .hide in custom css affect the results when the properties defined in Bootstrap ".hide" and custom css ".hide" are exactly same except having " !important " in addition which (i guess, please correct if i am wrong) implies that custom selector would be given preference?

i am trying to share the working version of my code using codepen, but i dont know why my code still does'nt wrok on codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RaGJwE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `!important` is always very strong. It could just be bypassed if you use a `display: block !important;` afterwards.

The simpliest way would be to not use the "hide" or "hidden" classes which are targeted by bootstrap. Just change the class to "hideit" or something else like in this updated fiddle:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MyjXOv

Comment: thanks for help @Simon Kraus, but i still can't find answer to my ques, why does using .hide create problems when definitions of both hides is same, plus the bootstrap hide's !important directs to use custom css's hide.

Comment: If you have ,hide in your css file in line 1 with display:none; and .hide in line 10 with display: block; the first one would be overwritten. If you use !important this has more weight. you could just overwrite it with another important in a later line. the same applies to different css files. it will be overwritten hierarchially. and jquery uses inline styles in its show() and hide() . this inline style has more weight like the classes in your style sheets but less weight than the !important declarations. hope this is somehow understandable :D

Comment: well as a newbie at Front End tech, this made me understand few new things, on my way to explore more on css hierarchies .. thank you.. @Simon Kraus..